# Update a Nested JSON object in MuleSoft DataWeave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4, anypoint-platform

Do I have a JSON object that looks like:

> {"application":{"desiredState":"STOPPED"}}

I need to create this object at runtime in DataWeave based on the value of desiredState passed at runtime which could be STOPPED or STARTED.

How can I do that in DataWeave 2.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want just to pass the value from the flow which I'll assume it is passed to the DataWeave script in a variable of the same name.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{"application": {"desiredState":vars.desiredState}}
```

Comment: I realized it later that I didn't have to build the the whole JSON and just pass the desiredState value to the existing json structure